# Inverting OP AMP SLEW RATE

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, slew-rate

I'm trying to do a question that requires me to design an inverting op-amp in multisim and find the slew rates in different scenarios using the OPAMP_5T_VIRTUAL operational amplifier model found in the multisim component library, and view the output on the oscilloscope.

The input to the op-amp is from a signal generator :

Triangular wave amplitude: 500mV

Triangular wave frequency: 11 kHz

The op-amp should have a gain of 6.

Here is my circuit design from my understanding 
[image: ![enter image description here]

the first part was to calculate the minimum slew rate, the virtual op amp values were not changed and the default slew rate is already set to 1M V/us.

[image]

so i simulated the circuit and the output was :

[image]

i placed the cursors in the linear region of the waveform in the oscilloscope to measure minimum slew rate : SR=∆2.395V/(∆36.290µs)=0.066 V/µs (is this value for minimum slew rate correct?)

In the next part of the question i have to simulate the circuit twice of the minimum slew rate and one fifth of the slew rate and the output waveforms should be on the same oscilliscope:

twice the minimum slew rate = 0.066 X 2 = 0.132

one fifth slew rate = 0.0132

To do this i set 2 circuits one circuit with slew rate of 0.132M and the other one with 0.0132, all other settings of the op amp are default and untouched.
[image]

[image]

So my circuit design now looks like this:
[image]

After running the simulation the output on the scope is:
[image]

The red wave(channel A) output is from the op-amp with slew rate of twice the minimum slew rate and the blue wave(channel B) output is from the opamp of one-fifth of the minimum slew rate. Is this simulation output correct?

also, what can i say to discuss the differences between simulation results that indicate slew rate distortion is taking place.

If anything is unclear and not understandable I apologize.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to measure slew rate, input a square wave, not a triangle.

Comment: Sorry, the question given requires me to input a Triangle wave.

Comment: The slope to measure the slew rate is the same for a square wave and triangle wave.
https://www.audioholics.com/audio-amplifier/amplifier-slew-rate/image_preview2

Comment: Yes, if you feed it a square wave, the slew rate will be immediately visible in the output as per your illustration.

Comment: I just simulated as square wave input the slew rate is exactly the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Triangular wave amplitude: 500mV
>   Triangular wave frequency: 11 kHz
>   The op-amp should have a gain of 6.

500mV seems to be peak to peak (Vpp) since you input 250mV in the amplitude field.

Output 6*0.5Vpp = 3Vpp

Period = 1/11k = 90.9µs

dv/dt = 3V per one half period = 66000V/s = 0.066 V/µs so your measurement is correct.

> The red wave(channel A) output is from the op-amp with slew rate of twice the minimum slew rate and the blue wave(channel B) output is from the opamp of one-fifth of the minimum slew rate. Is this simulation output correct?
>   also, what can i say to discuss the differences between simulation results that indicate slew rate distortion is taking place.

Yes, it looks correct, but I wonder why the question specified a triangle wave while a square wave (or a sine) would make it a lot more obvious and easier to understand. I mean, an opamp which is limited by its slew rate will output a triangle wave, so if you input a sine or a square and you get a triangle at the output, then you know it's happening. If you input a triangle at the input you will get a triangle at the output anyway, so you have to check if the amplitude and phase are correct to know if it is slewing, which is more complicated.

See [this article](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/slew-rate.php) for examples of slew rate distortion.